# Stuck with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I'm learning to code Kotlin as a hobby, but I've hit a wall. I'm getting the following error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: Array<(out) TypeVariable(T)!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, textViewResourceId: Int) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: (Mutable)List<TypeVariable(T)!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
```

It was working fine until I added the API from openweather to pull some data.
Any help appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.myweatherapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class ForecastActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forecast)



         var retriever = WeatherRetriever()

            val callback = object : Callback<Weather> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Weather>?, t: Throwable) {
                println("It failed")
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<Weather>?, response: Response<Weather>?) {
                    println("It wORKED")

                    println(response?.body()?.main)

                    title = response?.body()?.name

                    var forecasts = response?.body()?.main

                    var castListView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.forecastListView)

                    var adapter = ArrayAdapter(this@ForecastActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,forecasts)

                    castListView.adapter=adapter
                }

            }
            retriever.getForecast(callback)
        }

        }
```

Comment: What is the type of `Response.Body.Main`? It needs to be an Array or List. Also, you're going to have a problem if either the response or body is null.

Comment: I'm trying to get to the "Main" array on this JSON file, and to put the contents of it as the result: [link] https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3621224&units=metric&appid=ff2563aab36fc89bc7a3c4fe58dd7f3e

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayAdapter(this@ForecastActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,forecasts)
```

ArrayAdapter requires Array/List of Object as the third argument but `forecasts` is just the response body.

[See more details here about ArrayAdapter constructors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter)

You need to parse the response and prepare a List/Array of the Objects (i.e. String titles) to pass as the 3rd argument in the  ArrayAdapter constructor.